# Express website is accessible on certain devices but not on others

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

My website (anarchychess.xyz) is accessible through my PC and laptop, but on some other devices (mainly mobile phones but also a friend's PC) the browser shows the error:

#### This site can't be reached

#### anarchychess.xyz refused to connect

#### ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I can't figure out what would make it work on certain devices but not on others. The website uses React for front-end and ExpressJS for back-end. The express server is running on an AWS ec2 machine and the DNS service is AWS Route 53.

I'd appreciate it if anyone has an idea for what the reason could be or at least could tell me if they can access the website through their own device.

The server's code:

```
// server
import express from "express";

var app = express();

import * as path from "path";

// https
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as https from "https";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

var __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

var __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

import { AppServer } from "./app_server.js";

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../deployment/private_key.pem"), "utf8");
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../deployment/anarchychess_xyz.crt"), "utf8");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../build")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../build/index.html"));
});

app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});

var httpsServer = https.createServer({ key: privateKey, cert: certificate }, app);

httpsServer.listen(3031, "0.0.0.0", function () {
    console.log("server listening on port 3031");
});

var appServer = new AppServer(httpsServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]: Apparently the browser defaults to HTTP while my server only communicates over HTTPS. I needed to set up my server so that it redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS. There wasn't a problem on PC's that I've used before to code since I had previously used them to search for https://anarchychess.xyz/ so the browser there knew to default to that.